# assign spatially autocorrelated variable to turtles

Tags: netlogo

I want to assign a generated autocorrelated variable (0 to 1) to turtles spread over a grid. I can create autocorrelated data in **R** and then import them into **Netlogo**, but for sure, there is a more efficient way to do it in **Netlogo**.

Here a simple example:

```
turtles-own [
variable
]

to setup
  clear-all

create-turtles 30
   [ 
    move-to one-of patches with [ not any? turtles-here ]
    ; I would like to assign a spatially autocorrelated variable
    ; for now, I am using a uniform variable
    set variable random-float 1.0 
   ]

end
```

Here an example using **R**:

```
N <- 16 * 16
p <- 0.07

# generate some points
set.seed(1234)
x.coord <- rep(1:16, 16)
y.coord <- rep(1:16, each = 16)
points <- cbind(x.coord,y.coord)

# distance matrix between points
Dd <- as.matrix(dist(points))

# weights matrix
w <- exp(-p * Dd)
Ww <- chol(w)

# variable
z <- t(Ww) %*% rnorm(N,0,1)
z <- scale(z, center = min(z), scale = max(z) - min(z)) # rescale to 0-1 variable

# plot
require(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x = x.coord, y = y.coord, z = z)
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, col = z)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_colour_gradient(low="red", high="white")
```

Because I get data for each patch, I can create `variable` from the patch in which turtles are. Anyway, this looks unnecessarily complicated.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a reason not to e.g. just use the Sugarscape layout of sugar?  Also, what happens to "variable" when your turtles move?

Comment: No, I don't. I will check it. In my example, turtles are dwellings (they don't move), but they have a "variable" assigned: I want that variable to be spatially autocorrelated.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best solution, but at least it is close. I use the `k-means` extension to generate clusters based on distances between turtles. Then, I assign a random number between 0 to 1 + some noise to the turtles of each cluster.

```
let clusters k-means:cluster-by-xy targets 10 100 0.1
(foreach clusters (n-values 10 [random-float 1.0]) 
[ ask ?1 [ set variable random-between ?2 0.15 ]] ) ]
```

`random-between` is a report:

```
to-report random-between [number width-interval]
  let half-interval width-interval / 2
  let random-number (number - half-interval) + random-float width-interval
  if random-number < 0 [set random-number 0]
  if random-number > 1 [set random-number 1]
  report random-number
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not really clear - I don't believe you mean autocorrelated because you haven't mentioned time at all. Based on your R-code, you want to have turtles at regular points (in which case you want to `ask patches [ sprout 1 ]` rather than create turtles) and for them to have a variable with a value based on its position, in which case you can write a function with `xcor` and `ycor` as inputs.

Comment: spatial autocorrelation: a measure of the degree to which a set of spatial features and their associated data values tend to be clustered together in space (positive spatial autocorrelation) or dispersed (negative spatial autocorrelation)

Comment: okay, so the differences in values for agents is correlated with the distance between them? As well as agents knowing where they are with the `xcor` and `ycor` values I have already mentioned, there is a primitive for `distance`. If you want an actual solution, you are going to have to provide an equation or algorithm to be implemented.